# Email form validation to accept only one domain

Tags: php

I know this is a relatively asked question but here goes. I have registration form where a user can sign up but I want it to be for a closed group of people so only people from my company can register. So only people with @company.com domain addresses can register. What I have so far is just a email validation code using patterns. How would I alter the below code to only allow @company.com emails? Cheers.

```
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

}
```

Comment: relatively *frequent

Comment: at least add in the duplicate.

Comment: Not my downvote there, but I did find a duplicate for this. See the accepted answer in there or the other one. Both work.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit it like this

```
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@company.com$/';
```

You could use something easy in my opinion, like this with JS:

```
var email = 'youremail@company.com';

if (email.indexOf('@company.com') >= 0) {

   //do something

} else {

   //do something
}
```

It just an idea, and in the server side do something similar, I hope it can help you.

Comment: That's JS, OP didn't tag as such. I believe they want a PHP solution here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah it was my mistake and I updated my answer

Comment: *Ah, much better* ;-)